# Solving the diffusion equation with general initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know that the solution for the diffusion equation for a general initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ can be given in the form

$$u(x,t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4πDt}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4Dt}}dy$$

How do I find an explicit form for this solution when $f(x)=1$ for $x$ between $0$ and $a$, and $0$ otherwise? I was thinking maybe via changing the variables, but didn't reach much further...

It would be helpful if the solution was in terms of the error function $\operatorname{erf}(x)$.

Comment: The solution may be written as a difference of error functions since it involves integrating the Gaussian kernel $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}$ over some interval which varies in $(x,t)$. So I don't know what you mean by "explicit" because that's necessarily a non-elementary function.

Comment: @shalop basically what is u(x,t) when the f(x) is as above

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880854/using-the-fourier-transform-solve/3008423#3008423) is very close to what you're looking for. See if you can follow through it.